# Installing MySQL on MacOS

Tags: macos, installation, mysql, macports, xcode

I want to install mysql. Big Internet told me that I should do it via MacPorts. I've downloaded MacPort's dmg and it asks me to install XCode which I can buy via App Store. It is ridiculous to pay money to install free app (I mean MySQL) :).

So what can I do now?

*PS* I am new on mac after few years on CentOS/Ubuntu so I am familiar with the use of package managers such as `yum` or `apt` or installing via sources. It will be good to know about gcc, make and other stuff on mac

Comment: If you pay money for it it's hardly free, right? They obviously switched to a paid model with version 4, either via 100$ developer accounts or App Store.

Comment: I don't need any of mac developer tools. I need just mysql :) mysql is free

Comment: You need the dev tools if you want to compile from source, which is what you attempt to do with Macports.

Comment: unix dev tools ussualy wight less then 4GB distro

Comment: You could have just installed the dev tools that come with your Mac. Same size, no download. But no compiler without the IDE. It's a whole package. There's no "headless" OS X either, even if that's enough for a server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go to developer.apple.com, sign up for the free developer account, and download the XCode 3 version that is still offered. This is enough to do Macports and other open source stuff (you get gcc and all the header files you need).

Comment: thanx going to check it

Comment: __I need to download 4 Gigabytes of useles stuff to install mysql?__ WTF

Comment: yep, it's a lot of stuff. But eh, you've got a nice IDE as well (and all the iPhone stuff, like the simulator) I don't recall if there's an advanced install that disallows iPhone stuff, e.g.

Comment: Actually I don't need all this stuff. I've got TextMate and now I need MySQL and it looks crazy downloading this monster ). Thanks anyway

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/583360/gcc-without-xcode-on-os-x

Comment: So it seems like there is a customize option, going from that linked answer. Good. (I have all the stuff installed anyway, but I had enough space at the time).

Comment: space is not a problem at all :)

Answer (score 2):

Download MySQL from the [official web site](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/). [Instructions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/macosx-installation-pkg.html).

Comment: Looks like a good solution :) downloading