# MAMP set up from scratch on Lion OSX

Tags: mac, php, apache-http-server, mysql, osx-lion

How different is it from Snow Leopard to create a MySQL, Apache, PHP install from scratch (not MAMP) on Mac OSX 10.7 Lion?

Answer (score 1):

Apache+PHP is pretty simple. All you have to do is...

1. Start the Apache server from System Preferences->Sharing->Web Sharing.
2. Uncomment the php5_module in `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`. Load that file up in your favorite plaintext editor, search for the string "php", and remove the `#` from the beginning of the line.
3. Run `$ sudo apachectl graceful` in Terminal to reboot the Apache server with the new module active.

Installing MySQL can be slightly more hairy, but your best bet is to grab a DMG/PKG installer file from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/ (download the Mac OS X 10.6 64-bit DMG Archive) and follow your nose. There are some good Googlable resources for that (try `install mysql mac`) if you run into trouble, but once you've got the server running and automatically starting after reboot, it should be pretty easy to get PHP to talk to it.

Comment: @Steve For a long time, there were no MySQL install packages for OS X. If you search the web for instructions, make sure they explain how to set it up after installing the installer packages NReilingh linked to before following their instructions. [Or do you want to install Apple's developer tools if you don't have to?](http://superuser.com/questions/261256/installing-mysql-on-macos/261260#261260)

Answer (score 0):

I just did this last weekend so it's still fresh in my mind. I found this to be the most [helpful guide](http://echodittolabs.org/blog/2011/08/os-x-107-lion-development-native-mamp-mysql-installer
), Everything besides PEAR worked for me. And if you want some side-reading or what not I found [these](http://akrabat.com/php/setting-up-php-mysql-on-os-x-10-7-lion/) [two](http://php-osx.liip.ch/) just okay.

But really you should be fine. I'm totally enjoying my new environment following the first guide.

Comment: I forgot to mention that OS X Lion made some large changes to custom MAMP structure. It was quite annoying if you came from Snow Leopard like I did so those links also helped explain those changes to me. Cheers! :)